# Access FTP Server like Dropbox API does

Tags: ide, dropbox, sourcekit

In my quest for a suitable Cloud IDE, I came across [SourceKit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iieeldjdihkpoapgipfkeoddjckopgjg?hl=en-US), a Chrome extension that lets you edit your Dropbox files using the Ace/Bespin syntax highlighter. It's great! Except I don't really use my dropbox public folder as my web server :/

So I looked into the [source code](https://github.com/kenotron/sourcekit) and it's 100% javascript -- it uses the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs) to send/receive files. The Dropbox API uses REST instead of FTP.

So I thought - what if I could communicate with my FTP server using REST, just like Dropbox does? Then I could just plug that into SourceKit and modify my FTP server's files from a browser tab!

But after considerable googling, I've determined it's either impossible or I'm using the wrong terminology. I can't be the first person to try to do this.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the owner of the FTP Server, maybe you could implement a REST HTTP client which would, then, answer the REST calls from the client (which would be SourceKit), but for normal FTP access (which is a protocol itself, like HTTP), you can't do it via REST (REST is just HTTP), you would need to do it via FTP calls.

Because Chrome plugins are written in Javascript and only Javascript, and because [FTP is impossible with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4594819/973380) (all the solutions the Google Search returns use a server-side script or a Java applet), it is all impossible.