# how copy files from google drive to an ftp server using google app scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, ftp, sftp

I have a project on Google App Scripts connected to my drive.
I was able to save and organize my files (from mail) and directories in the drive using the script.
now, I want to save the files to an FTP server and cannot find the References to do so.

how do I access an ftp server, create folders and upload files to them ?

thanks

Comment: I can confirm @noogui answer. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594798/download-file-from-ftp-via-javascript/4594819#4594819[1]

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not possible. If you check this [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app), app script only supports HTTP and HTTPS communication over the internet. A supporthing [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894694/fetch-images-from-ftp-server-using-google-apps-script) seems to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround to go from GAS -> FTP is as follows.  I've been using this method for a number of years in production.

1. From apps script, save the file to google drive
2. Using Zapier, trigger to copy new filesfrom the google drive folder to a DropBox folder
3. Using Microsoft Flow, trigger to copy new files from the Dropbox folder to an FTP or SFTP location.

You can probably do step 3 in Zapier as well.  I use Microsoft Flow because I already had a significant number of automated tasks setup there.  For Step, 2, I use Zapier because MS flow does not yet have a built-in trigger available based on a new file being saved to google drive.  You would have to make your own custom trigger using the google drive API's.